# Pass data with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have the following contentString for a infowindow for google maps. I'm having a hard time figuring out something I'm sure its simple, but I cant seem to be able to send data with my clickTest function. In this case I want to send the data for location.

```
var contentString =
              "<div>" +
              "<a ng-click=clickTest()>" + location.activityNumber + "</a>" +
              "<br><a>" + location.customer + "</a>" +
              "<br><a>" + location.orderClass + "</a>" +
              "<br><a>" + location.accountNumber + "</a>" +
              "<br><a>" + location.date + "</a>" +
              "<br><a>" + location.serviceRegion + "</a>" +
              "<br><a>" + location.techid + "</a>" +
              "<br><a>" + location.phoneNumber + "</a>" +
              "<br><a>" + location.address + "</a>" +
              "<br><a>" + location.city + ', ' + location.state + ', ' + location.zip + "</a>" +
              "</div>";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to bind `contentString ` variable to html

Comment: It's already binder to html problem is that if I change ng-click=clickTest(location) I can't see location variable on back end

Comment: Your HTML isnt even valide. Why don't you use ng-templates for your template creation. This is far away from all AngularJS standard handlings.

Comment: It becomes valid html once I use $compile. I don't think thats my issue here.

Comment: could you provide your controller which has `var location` or `$scope.location`, your html and what do you want to pass on `ng-click="clickTest(???)"` because if you want to send just activityNumber then `"<a ng-click=\"clickTest(+location.activityNumber+)\">"` should works well.

Anyway, if you can share controller and html, it's better to see the clear picture.

Comment: @AimeTPGM yes this is what I'm trying to do however your example gives me the following error. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=)&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=36&p3=clickTest(%2Blocation.activityNumber%2B)&p4=

Comment: you need to provide a better code example ... all you showed us here is a variable ...

Comment: @fpena06 Could we have the relavant part of your JS code with HTML? So we can figure out what is going on.